# Change the font of the new "No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA"

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, fonts, recaptcha

The new reCAPTCHA is awesome. Almost everything is great, except one thing. Its font. It's quite stupid to use a font that doesn't support other languages. My website is in Hebrew, and the font that the reCAPTCHA shows is awful. How can I change it?

Is there a Google Api for that? Does it possible to edit the CSS of iframe (cross-domain)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that, currently, it is not possible. It is just an image generated with text, so the font should be basically available on the reCaptcha server.

Comment: @sємsєм, I'm not talking about the old recaptcha / recaptcha's image. I'm talking about the font of "I'm not a robot" in the iframe of the new No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA

Answer (score 1):

reCAPTCHA is loaded via `<iframe>` so customization with your own CSS is not possible, only through reCAPTCHA API.

Using reCAPTCHA API you can implicitly define the language using `hl` parameter as shown below, with `hl=iw` for Hebrew. See [full list of language codes](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language) for more information.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=iw" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also it supports two color themes - `dark` and `light`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=iw" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-theme="dark"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

See [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already knew it. The reCAPTCHA is in Hebrew in my website, the problem is the font. The font Google uses doesn't support hebrew, so the text, and eventually the whole website looks owfol, just because of that. http://prntscr.com/6w7ug6

Comment: Please explain what's wrong with the picture you've posted, looks fine to me.

Comment: The font. I believe you can't see the difference in fonts in Hebrew, I won't notice difference in Arabic / Russian fonts. But trust me, that's really awful font. That's the font that being shown when you don't set font, that the default (the font that you see when you done with the HTML but didn't started with CSS). 

Usually I don't mind, but that font is extremely ugly...

Comment: Vlad, I see that you've posted on reCAPTCHA forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/Ew5Ira-7OnQ), maybe we'll get response from Google dev team.

Answer (score 0):

ReCaptcha API does provide localization. You have to provide the parameter "hl=iw" for Hebrew. See their [Language Codes API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language) for more supported languages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already knew it. The reCAPTCHA is in Hebrew in my website, the problem is the font. The font Google uses doesn't support hebrew, so the text, and eventually the whole website looks owfol, just because of that. http://prntscr.com/6w7ug6